# Is there a way to make a K-star have an unusually strong stellar wind

Tags: stars

I have been making a planet and its star for some time now.

## Background

In a previous question, I asked how a star could develop an O VII forbidden line and I generally realized that the star needed to have strong stellar winds so that using MCWS (magnetically confined wind shocks), the star could generate x-rays. Then, I could make the x-rays excite neon high in my planet's atmosphere and create "pseudo-aurorae", which would create these orange aurorae sort of things that could be seen by the life on the planet.

---

Requirements:

- Give a way where my star could generate a larger stellar wind
- This method must not harm life on my nearby habitable planet (so no flare stars)
- Also it has to be possible when the star is in the main sequence (sorry no T-Tauri K stars)
- No handwaving
- I would be interested in seeing a natural and a artificial technological approach, but natural would be slightly better

## Question

I then realized that normally cooler stars like my K2V star have weak winds, so is there any plausible way to make my star have a strong wind (please don't handwave and thanks)?

Comment: The solar wind is a bunch of particles that are too hot (fast) for the star's gravity to contain. A low tech approach might be to use highly reflective foils to reflect star light back to the coronasphere, supply more heat, more particles escaping. Good Q, I'm interested in seeing answers.

Comment: @BMF Thank you for complement and the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> normally cooler stars like my K2V star have weak winds, so is there any plausible way to make my star have a strong wind (please don't handwave and thanks)?

I am not as savvy on astrophysics as some users from this site whom I deeply admire, but I do remember that ε Eridani has very strong winds (compared to our Sun). Indeed, checking [its entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_Eridani), we find this:

> The star is estimated to be less than a billion years old. This relative youth gives Epsilon Eridani a higher level of magnetic activity than the Sun, with a stellar wind 30 times as strong.

And it's a K2V just like your star. It's a natural (as far as we know) occurrence of a K2V with very strong winds, so the fact that it exists should make your own star from your world realistic.

As to why Eridani has such strong winds, maybe the star is just like me. I also had a period in my life when I was young and hot, and somehow I passed stronger winds back then. Other than that I lack the physics to explain how it can be so.

Comment: I'm just wondering, but your example (ε Eridani) is pretty young, so is it possible that an older K2V star (like around our Sun's age) could have a stellar wind? I am leaning towards yes, because the wind in ε Eridani is 30 times the solar wind so maybe after 3.5 billion years, it could still retain a strong(er) wind.

Comment: @NeilIyer I don't have the knowledge to answer that but as far as I remember the wind strength is somehow related to the star's temperature, so as long as it is hot it might have strong winds.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to make my star slightly hotter?

Comment: @NeilIyer Swallowing a Jupiter-sized planet would make the star slightly hotter for about one Earth year. I can't think of anything else other than making the star more massive.

Comment: Ok, I could just make my star like ε Eridani, but have even stronger winds and those would fade over time, but if I start out with some planet-eating stuff and something like ε Eridani but only more so, this could work.